# Parsing a HTTP Basic authentication with an email containing a colon character ( ':' )

Tags: http, parsing, email, rest, authentication

I'm using the Authorization header with the Basic type for authentication.
I'm following the [HTTP Basic authentication specifications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) which states that the credentials should follow this form -> userIdentifier:password encoded in base64

We are using an email as the user identifier and according to the [email format specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address), the colon(':') character is permitted.

The colon(':') is also a valid character in the password.

Knowing this, I'm looking for a creative way to parse the credentials part of the header that uses a colon(':') as the separator between userID and password.

In this case it's simple -> francis@gmail.com:myPassword

This is where it gets complicated -> francis@gmail.com:80:myPasswordWith:Inside

francis@gmail.com:80 is a valid email according to the email format specification even though this is not used very often. So where do I know where to split ?

We have made the decision not to accept an email containing a ':'. But we want to notify the user that his email is not valid, how can we ensure that we are splitting the string at the right place ?

Hope I asked my question in a clear manner, don't hesitate to ask for more details

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don’t notify the user that the *email* is invalid. Split according to the RFC 2617 rules (everything after the first colon is the password), then try to authenticate, fail, and return a generic “authentication failure” message.

A situation where `john@example.org:80` has password `secret` and `john@example.org` has password `80:secret` at the same time, seems unrealistic.

If you require your users to register, you probably do it with some other mechanism (forms?) where you can easily separate the username and tell that it is invalid.